# including the trailing slash to end of ".DIR."

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory

here is my code, I want to make an activation link, Im using this code:

```
a href='".DIR."login/activate.phpx=$id&y=$activasion'
```

BUT i got it like http://mysite.comlogin/activate.php

how I can add a trailing slash to the end of my URL or something else

also, I tried

```
a href='".DIR."/login/activate.phpx=$id&y=$activasion'
```

and this one doesn't work too

Thank you for help

Comment: *"how I can add a trailing slash to the end of my URL or something else"* - you mean you want `http://mysite.comlogin/activate.php/` ? I don't get the question. You seem to want to add a slash after `DIR` but seem to not be using that correctly, seems you want to use the `__DIR__` magic constant, right? Your *"how I can add a trailing slash to the end of my URL"*  and what I get out of this, is that you want `http://mysite.comlogin/activate.php/`.

Comment: I already tried this way as I wrote, It doesn't work. I use this code for a php mailer, when I add slash I receive nothing

Comment: *"doesn't work"* - isn't very descriptive. What do you get and what do you want to get as a result? Your question is written in such a way that it isn't clear what it is you're asking; it needs to be rephrased and being specific. I for one have no idea what it is that you want.

Comment: no I want to add slash after .com

Comment: Why is this tagged `.htaccess`? Where do you define `DIR` ? Maybe just add a slash there? Although your second "example" looks like it should do it

Comment: I wil check that, Thnak you

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
define("DIR", $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]);
echo '<a href="http://'.DIR.'/login/activate.phpx='.$id.'&y='.$activasion.'">';
```

Comment: It's pretty great way, but I have a subdomain so it will be `http://foo.example.com/active.php?` is it possible to define domain `example.com`

Comment: sure: 
`$fullHost = explode(".", $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]);
$hostWithoutSubdomain = fullHost[count($fullHost)-1] . fullHost[count($fullHost)-2];`

Comment: There is a problem with my php mailer, when i send a php link then mailer block messages